# Spring boot, mongo DB how to compare column value for greater than 0

Tags: spring, mongodb

The application is in spring boot and mongo db.

I  would like to find for all records, where prize is grater than 0 and some other criteria.

I tried with something like this,

```
   @Query("{'prize' : {$gt : ?0 }, 'logDate' : {$lt : ?1} , 'api' : ?2 , 'service' : ?3}")
    List<SomeLog> findByLogDateBeforeAndApiAndService(double prizeZero,Date endDateAndTime, ApiName apiName, String service);
```

Where I'm explicitly sending the prizeZero as an parameter as 0.0. and comparing with prize. It works fine.

But I'm looking for, how can I avoid prizeZero parameter, and compare the prize directly in query, as we do in plain SQL just like `prize > 0`

So tried with,

```
  @Query("{'prize' : {$gt : 0 }, 'logDate' : {$lt : ?1} , 'api' : ?2 , 'service' : ?3}")
    List<SomeLog> findByLogDateBeforeAndApiAndService(Date endDateAndTime, ApiName apiName, String service);
```

But it gives an error as,

Invalid parameter index! You seem to have declare too little query method parameters!

Can somebody suggest me how should I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're using "?3" which suggests there are 4 parameters but you only have 3. Maybe try to -1 to all your param positions in your string:
`@Query("{'prize' : {$gt : 0 }, 'logDate' : {$lt : ?0} , 'api' : ?1 , 'service' : ?2}")`